# ios custom block can not compile for arm64

Tags: ios, compilation, block, arm64

When change to arm64 from armv7s, I can't compile the custom block. How I can reslove the problem? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```html
//typedef NSInteger (^ActionSheetPickerNumberOfRowsBlock)

(ActionSheetPicker *picker);
    ActionSheetPickerNumberOfRowsBlock numberOfRows = ^(ActionSheetPicker *picker) {
        return 29;
    };
```

Comment: The error: Incompatible block pointer types initializing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`29` defaults to type `int`, so the compiler infers return type `int` for the block, instead of `NSInteger` as needed. `NSInteger` is the same as `int` in armv7, but not arm64.

You can see from [this table](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH2-SW8):

- `int` is 32-bit in both armv7 and arm64
- `NSInteger` is 32-bit in armv7 and 64-bit in arm64
- `long` is 32-bit in armv7 and 64-bit in arm64 (same as `NSInteger`)

So you can either do:

```
return 29l;
```

or

```
return (NSInteger)29;
```

or explicitly specify the return type in the block literal:

```
^NSInteger(ActionSheetPicker *picker) {
    return 29;
};
```